# Debian 11 - sysctl parameter 'net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_tcp_be_liberal' cannot be changed

Tags: debian, configuration, sysctl

I want to set to `1` the value of the sysctl parameter `net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_tcp_be_liberal` on some Debian 11-based systems I have, but I'm finding it impossible to do so. I've tried the following:

- Setting the value in the `/etc/sysctl.conf` file, then executing `sudo sysctl -p`. For some reason, only when I set the value in that file `sysctl` seems to be aware of the change and truly applies it. After a reboot the value returns to its original `0` value.
- The command `sudo sysctl -w net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_tcp_be_liberal=1` works but, as expected, the change is lost after a reboot.
- The command `echo '1' | sudo tee /proc/sys/net/netfilter/nf_conntrack_tcp_be_liberal` works too but also the change is lost after rebooting.
- I've used `sudo grep -rwn nf_conntrack_tcp_be_liberal /folder-name` to try finding any other file that may have the `nf_conntrack_tcp_be_liberal` value set as `0`, but it seems there's none.
- I've also checked with `sudo modprobe -c` if the parameter happened to be also a module one, but it doesn't seem to be the case. I was inspired to check this by [the answer to this other question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/410811/difference-between-modprobe-and-sysctl-w-in-terms-of-setting-system-parameters).

After all of the above, I ran out of ideas. I hope anyone here can help me with this issue.

Comment: Do you have a symlink `/etc/sysctl.d/99-sysctl.conf` pointing to `/etc/sysctl.conf` (or `../sysctl.conf`)?

Comment: Yes, there's such symlink @StephenKitt, which points to `../sysctl.conf`.